# Почему разные значения __proto__ при разных выводах в консоль?

Tags: javascript

Всем добрый день.

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему при таком коде:

```
const user = { name: 'Ivan' };
console.log(user.__proto__.__proto__);
```

В консоль выводится `null` (как и должно быть)?

А если сделаю вот так:

```
const user = { name: 'Ivan' };
console.log(user);
```

То свойство `__proto__` у `Object.prototype` НЕ равно null?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть почему-то оно равно опять же `Object.prototype`. И вот в этом `__proto__`, которое должно быть равно `null`, уже в нём, когда еще раз раскрою `__proto__`, то только тогда уже `null`.

Или вот еще пример:

```
function User(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
const user = new User('Ivan');
console.log(user);
```

То вот опять:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если сделать вот так, то всё норм:

```
function User(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
const user = new User('Ivan');
console.log(user.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__);
```

Выводится `null`.

Объясните пожалуйста, почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каждый объект имеет объект-прототип. Конкретный объект наследует все свойства и методы у своего объекта-прототипа. У объекта-прототипа может быть свой собственный объект-прототип. Это называется цепочкой прототипов. Благодаря этому механизму объектам доступны свойства и методы которые определены в других объектах.

Точка не то же самое что стрелочка в консоли. Точка это оператор, который используется для доступа к свойствам и методам объекта. Если свойство не находится в конкретном экземпляре объекта, то оно ищется вверх по цепочке прототипов, пока не будет найдено или пока не будет достигнутого самого верхнего объекта. Стрелочка в консоли просто разворачивает объект, без поиска свойств и методов в цепочке прототипов. Поэтому вы видите разные результаты при разных выводах в консоль.

Выполните следующий код в консоле браузера:

```
test0 = { a: 'qwe' };
test1 = { b: 'asd' };
test2 = { c: 'zxc' };

Object.setPrototypeOf(test1, test0);
Object.setPrototypeOf(test2, test1);

console.log(test2.a, test2.b, test2.c);
console.log(test2);
```

Вы увидите, что оператор точки получит значение свойств a, b и c. Также, развернув объект test2 и его прототипы вы увидите всю цепочку.

[image]

В вашем случаи, написав строку user.**proto**.**proto** движек js сначала попробовал найти свойство **proto** в текущем объекте. Не нашел его там и начал искать **proto** в объекте-прототипе.

Comment: Благодарю, теперь понял.